# Password Protected SQL Server Backup

Tags: sql-server

I have a password protected sql server backup file that I need to restore.  In checking all available documentation I believe that the "password protection" doesn't alter the backup file in any way, it's totally readable, it's just there to help ensure that a restore doesn't occur to the wrong database.

Is there a way for me to do the restore without knowing the password (can I get it out of the backup file or remote it)?

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: What version sqlserver are you running? Was the password protection done through sql encryption?

Comment: It's a sql server 2005 install.  The backup was created using a password, not encrypted, so all the data within it is in cleartext.  I did manage to figure out the password and was able to restore to another sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a 3rd party data comparison tool such as RedGate's SQL Data Compare.  It may let you get around it.  You can demo it from their website for free.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm